# Analyzing DNS packet from dataset in python

Tags: python, dns

I have a big dataset into `.jason` and `.avro`

But I want to parse UDP and DNS to analyze each packet, inspecting into the data field, on my purpose in python.

Anyway, I'm a beginner in this field. Could Anyone recommend tools for me? (Also, guide If possible)

I only found a sniffing way by `Scapy` For me, I only want to analyze it based on my dataset.

Comment: For any DNS needs, look at DNS library `dnspython` it should cater for all your needs. For all the rest your question is not detailed enough to know how to help. What did you try already? Don't expect anyone here to write the code in your place, you should start something and then ask questions.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thank you for recommending me dnspython. 
to be clear, I want to parse FQDN and A records to find randomized subdomains for each packet from the dataset.

Comment: `I want to parse FQDN and A records`: given a DNS packet as captured "on the wire",  `dnspython` will be able to parse and analyze it in any way you need. Also some related mandatory advises: DNS is over UDP AND TCP (don't believe all wrong resources online stating it is UDP and maybe sometimes TCP, that is untrue), and also depending on where you capture traffic do note/remember that more and more browsers for example are using DNS over HTTPS hence capturing packets at the network level won't allow you to get really the DNS packet.